# Ruby on rails. bad value for range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

I am trying to pass date variable from form to method to export info based on created_at field in database. But when i send date format value from my form I get "bad value for range" error. I think it is because variable date format and format in database doesn't match. Any ideas how to solve that?

Here is my .haml form created with simple form:

```
= simple_form_for :download, { url: download_exports_path('xlsx') } do |f|
  = f.input :date, as: :date, html5: true
  = f.button :submit, "Export"
```

And here is my download method in my controller:

```
   def download
      current_time = Time.now
      date = params[:date]
      @addresses = Address::where(created_at: date..DateTime.now.end_of_day)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.xlsx {render xlsx: 'download',filename: "addresses.xlsx"}
        end
   end
```

Here is where i get error:
[image]

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause should start with a dot and also you should probably convert the date params to the correct format with `to_datetime`.

```
def download
  current_time = Time.now
  date = params[:download][:date].to_datetime
  @addresses = Address.where(created_at: date..DateTime.now.end_of_day)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {render xlsx: 'download',filename: "addresses.xlsx"}
    end
end
```

Comment: It says undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass if i do like you said with that .to_datetime

Comment: This is because `params[:date]` is nil. It should probably be `params[:download][:date]` if I am seeing your request parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `date` local variable is not a DateTime, just a string. You're trying to create a range that has different types at each end, not allowed.